# How can I run tests that are not in lib.rs or main.rs?

Tags: unit-testing, rust

I am learning to write unit tests in rust. However, I can't get my test running when they are not in `src/lib.rs` or `src/main.rs`.

I created a project with the following structure:

```
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
├── src
    ├── lib.rs
    └── main.rs
    └── functions.rs
```

and added the following code:

**main.rs**

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod test {
    #[test]
    fn test_main() {}
}
```

**lib.rs**

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod test {
    #[test]
    fn test_lib() {}
}
```

**functions.rs**

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod test {
    #[test]
    fn test_functions() { }
}
```

When I run `cargo test`, this is what I got:

```
Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.01s
     Running target\debug\deps\rust_unittests-b0ed92af162e0288.exe

running 1 test
test test::test_lib ... ok

test result: ok. 1 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out

     Running target\debug\deps\rust_unittests-c4edac234e8e3d9a.exe

running 1 test
test test::test_main ... ok

test result: ok. 1 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out

   Doc-tests rust_unittests

running 0 tests

test result: ok. 0 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out
```

The test function in main.rs and lib.rs were run as expected but the one in functions.rs wasn't.

I read the Rust book and several articles I Googled but none have mentioned this problem. What am I missing?

Comment: You need to have `mod functions;` in lib.rs (or main.rs, it's unclear from your code) in order to tell the compiler that the file needs to be read.

Comment: You may wish to read the [Separating Modules into Different Files](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch07-02-modules-and-use-to-control-scope-and-privacy.html#separating-modules-into-different-files) part of [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/).

Comment: Add an empty main in function.rs (`fn main() {}`). Then tell your Cargo manifest (here the `Cargo.toml` file) that there is a new executable crate (`[[bin]]`) whose `path` is `src/functions.rs`. `cargo test` will create an executable for excuting `src/functions.rs`'s tests.